# Fast Simulation of Mass-Spring system - Formula wrong?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, physics, matrix-calculus

I'm reading through [Fast Simulation of Mass-Spring Systems](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Eladislav/liu13fast/liu13fast.pdf) and I'm trying to understand the paper.
To a first read it seems easy enough.

However in section 4 formula (11) doesn't convince me

$$
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^s k_i \left\lVert p_{i_1} - p_{i_2} - d_i \right\rVert^2 = \frac{1}{2}x^T L x - x^T Jd
$$

Essentially on the lhs each $p_{i_1}, p_{i_2} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $d_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$
and $k_i \in \mathbb{R}$ on the rhs $x \in \mathbb{R}^{3m}$ $d \in \mathbb{R}^{3s}$, $L \in \mathbb{R}^{3m \times 3m}$ and $J \in \mathbb{R}^{3m \times 3s}$.

Unless I'm missing something isn't the formula wrong? Indeed if for all $i_1, i_2$ we set $p_{i_1} = p_{i_2} = 0$ we end up with

$$
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^s k_i \left\lVert d_i\right\rVert^2 = 0
$$

Which holds iff $d_i = 0$ for $i = 1,\ldots s$. The formula to me should be corrected as

$$
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^s k_i \left\lVert p_{i_1} - p_{i_2} - d_i \right\rVert^2 = \frac{1}{2}x^T L x - x^T Jd + \frac{1}{2} d^T A d
$$

where

$$
\frac{1}{2} d^T A d = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^s k_i \left\lVert d_i\right\rVert^2
$$

So again, isn't the formula in the paper wrong? (which I'd find a bit strange since the paper was published at Siggraph 2013).

Comment: Study Formula 9 through Formula 11, and you'll see that $\|d_i\|$ represents the **_rest length_** of the $i^{th}$ spring. Therefore setting $p_{i_1}=p_{i_2}$ is not realistic, since it would represent a spring of rest length zero.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. $d$ is optimized as well so it should be part of the quadratic expression to me. Can you please write a full answer explaining your thoughts?

Comment: As described in the third paper page under the section 4 Method, $p_i, p_j$ are the end points and $r$ the rest length. Well, if $p_i = p_j$ then $r = 0$  as expected.

Comment: @Cesareo I still don't get how the formula is derived given the assumption and a complete answer on where the assumption is exploited would be great.